# Google Sheet convert time format to another

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets, time, timestamp

Whenever I extract raw data from this specific tool I am getting the date format of

```
Fri Sep  2 10:29:50 2022
Fri Sep  9 10:31:01 2022
Mon Sep 12 10:32:28 2022
```

and I am having a hard time converting it to this kind of format in Google Sheet

```
9/2/2022 10:29
9/9/2022 10:31
9/12/2022 10:32
```

Already tried using different of formating but still can't convert it to the above format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A5="",,REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(A1:A5), 
 "(.*) (.*) (.*) (.*) (.*)", "$2/$3/$5 $4")*1))
```

[image]

then do:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Date value

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,
 DATEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(A2:A), "(.+\d{1,2}) \d{1,2}:")&" "&REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, " (....\z)"))+
 TIMEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(A2:A), " (\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}) "))))
```

[image]

### Custom date and time formats

[image]

### Custom number formats

[image]